# How do I reference to a text files Content?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

[react.js]
I'm trying to refer to the content of a txt file but it if I reference to the file it will show me the path. how do I reference to the contents of the file? //the bashcode contains a bash cURL from failed API calls

[code]

```
import Bashcode from './Bashcode.txt';

<button onClick={() => navigator.clipboard.writeText(Bashcode)}>Naar Postman</button>
```

[expectations]
I was actually expecting to reference to the file to get or just the file name or the contents but turned out it referenced the path to the file.

Comment: imports are usually there to import code, so I don't know how your build-pipeline handles the import of a `.txt`. Did you try to debug your code? What does `Bashcode` contain?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `File Reader` module to achieve this.

```js
import Bashcode from './Bashcode.txt';

<button onClick={() => {
  let _fr = new FileReader();
  const fileContents = _fr.readAsText(Bashcode);
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(fileContents)
}}>Naar Postman</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button onClick={() => {
                      
                      fetch(Bashcode)
                      .then(r => r.text())
                      .then(text => {
                        // console.log('text decoded:', text);
                        navigator.clipboard.writeText(text);
                      });
                      }}>Copy Bash cURL</button>
```